# Check permission on item in list

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

In a list where items only can be changed by owner or admin how can I check by code if a user can edit the item.

I try

```
item.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EditListItems);
```

it will return True as the user can add and edit items in list.

Comment: As a dirty fix I now check who created the item and compare to current user.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the user against author field may be the only way to go.

Alternatively you can limit the list of items the user can try to edit by making a query that only brings back items they are the author of unless they have broader rights.

Check for broader rights using the SPRoleDefinition and SPRoleAssignment classes.

Other wise just try the edit and catch the exception and raise it back to the user.